# How to swap keys on keyboard in Xubuntu?

Tags: linux, keyboard

I am switching to Xubuntu from Windows to run emulated game consoles. Some emulators do not support remapping of admin keys. Because this system will be in an arcade cabinet with limited keys available (and the keyboard encoder doesn't easily use all keys), I want every function to use the same key across all emulators.

In Windows, this was easy enough with AHK. I'm trying to figure out how to do a simple key swap in Linux, but haven't been able to do so. I want the custom keyboard layout to be loaded on-demand (without requiring an X restart) when a game starts, and then revert back to the normal layout when the game exits. I think setxkbmap can do this, but I'm not sure. All the directions I've seen for modifying your keyboard layout with this tool are for making some pre-defined alternate key mapping. I haven't found the rule for "To make any key send any other key, do this..."

Two of the key swaps I need make to are to have the "p" key send the "pause/break" key, and the "Esc" key send Alt+F4 (I know this one is trying to get one key to send two keys, so it might be trickier). Can somebody tell me the easiest way to do these?